# Correct way of subscribing to Phoenix PubSub with Genserver

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

Ive been trying to instantiate a genserver process that will subscribe to PubSub in Phoenix framework, these are my files and errors:

config.ex:

```
config :excalibur, Excalibur.Endpoint,
  pubsub: [
    adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2,
    name: Excalibur.PubSub
  ]
```

Module using genserver:

```
defmodule RulesEngine.Router do
  import RulesEngine.Evaluator
  use GenServer
  alias Excalibur.PubSub

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_) do
    {:ok, {Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(PubSub, :evaluator)}}
    IO.puts("subscribed")
  end

  # Callbacks

  def handle_info(%{}) do
    IO.puts("received")
  end

  def handle_call({:get, key}, _from, state) do
    {:reply, Map.fetch!(state, key), state}
  end
end
```

and when i do a iex -S mix this error happens:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application excalibur: Excalibur.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: RulesEngine.Router
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe/2
            (phoenix_pubsub 1.1.2) lib/phoenix/pubsub.ex:151: Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(Excalibur.PubSub, :evaluator)
            (excalibur 0.1.0) lib/rules_engine/router.ex:11: RulesEngine.Router.init/1
            (stdlib 3.12.1) gen_server.erl:374: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib 3.12.1) gen_server.erl:342: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib 3.12.1) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

So which is the correct way to spin up a Genserver that will subscribe  to the PubSub topic ?

Comment: I think  subscribed `topic` should be string not atom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As by documentation, [`Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#subscribe/3) has the following spec:

```
@spec subscribe(t(), topic(), keyword()) :: :ok | {:error, term()}
```

where `@type topic :: binary()`. That said, your `init/1` should look like

```rb
def init(_) do
  {:ok, {Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(PubSub, "evaluator")}}
  |> IO.inspect(label: "subscribed")
end
```

Please note I also altered `IO.puts/1` to `IO.inspect/2` to preserve the returned value.